# Does the binary mean anything?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

In the puzzles of 16's files where you need to scan an image, sometimes there are hidden areas which have in binary.

Do these have any secret meaning like with the Moon Landing images the US flag is the Abstergo insignia and the banner is the Templar one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the different code (not all of which are in binary, by the way) do have special meaning.
[Here](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Decryptions_of_The_Truth) you can find a list of the codes found in 16's glyphs, along with their meaning.

---

The following are limited to the binary secrets.

```
01010011 01110101 01101101 01100101  
01110010 01101001 01100001 01101110  
00101110 00100000 01001101 01100101  
00100000 00110010 00110011 00101110
```

> When decoded as binary ASCII, the hidden text read "Sumerian. Me 23.", referring to the Sumerian Tablets of Destiny. Me 23 governed weaponry, which implied that the Piece of Eden that helped the Chinese invent gunpowder weapons was synonymous with the 23rd Me.

---

```
00110001 00110111 00100000 01001010  
01110101 01101100 01111001 00101100  
00100000 00110001 00111001 00110001
00111000
```

> When interpreted as binary ASCII, the hidden text read "17 July 1918", which was the date that Czar Nicholas II was executed.

---

```
00110011 00110000 00100000 01001101  
01100001 01111001 00101100 00100000  
00110001 00110100 00110011 00110001
```

> When interpreted as binary ASCII, the hidden text read "30 May 1431", which was the date Jeanne d'Arc was burned at the stake.